Trying to pivot_longer
This is probably silly, but I'm stuck anyways.
I have the following data frame:
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                                    SID = c(1L,1L,1L,3L,
                                                            3L,3L),
                                                Session = c("S1","S2","S3",
                                                            "S1","S2","S3"),
                                               MFTtot_i = c(1.16096180958124,
                                                            1.87516174147236,
                                                            1.3580435133394,
                                                            -0.023025382044371,
                                                            0.868949787147092,
                                                            0.818544049664308),
                                               MFTtot_c = c(0.424148875127088,
                                                            0.736624515913625,
                                                            0.582331945383079,
                                                            -0.360646914296501,
                                                            -0.102616395125987,
                                                            0.568374287100884),
                                               MFTnpl_i = c(1.12992057802027,
                                                            1.72414763597092,
                                                            1.31992512820668,
                                                            -0.0459400083029988,
                                                            0.877552197432715,
                                                            0.833016259746254),
                                               MFTnpl_c = c(0.380956173964173,
                                                            0.612695787806214,
                                                            0.548948423945319,
                                                            -0.415754151769206,
                                                            -0.11377875425023,
                                                            0.5318669978851),
                                             deltatot_i = c(1.2949199223707,
                                                            1.47291843448085,
                                                            1.80201609548309,
                                                            0.448439366625241,
                                                            1.44254893643999,
                                                            1.24614305780384),
                                             deltatot_c = c(0.581046925771083,
                                                            0.578171233537724,
                                                            0.846725209056708,
                                                            0.0907660716228413,
                                                            0.352169086263345,
                                                            0.756722046864607),
                                             deltanpl_i = c(1.14163440022334,
                                                            1.22744666268519,
                                                            1.74076846194607,
                                                            0.38921668722747,
                                                            1.36582548005673,
                                                            1.1752183263734),
                                             deltanpl_c = c(0.513444506949558,
                                                            0.523413611304003,
                                                            0.847610692032168,
                                                            0.0306054931267458,
                                                            0.311101974170304,
                                                            0.71131177638372),
                                                nepsraw = c(1275L,1595L,
                                                            1595L,1574L,1591L,
                                                            1592L),
                                                nrejeps = c(57L,182L,69L,
                                                            35L,0L,0L),
                                            ngoodtrls_c = c(845L,1061L,
                                                            1145L,1144L,1190L,
                                                            1192L),
                                            ngoodtrls_i = c(316L,350L,379L,
                                                            385L,399L,398L))

I just want to get it into long format using the _ to define the key value pair so that it looks like this, where _c and _i become a key called "congruency"
test<-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  SID = c(1L,1L,1L,3L,
          3L,3L,1L,1L,1L,3L,
          3L,3L),
  Session = c("S1","S2","S3",
              "S1","S2","S3","S1","S2","S3",
              "S1","S2","S3"),
  MFTtot = c(1.16096180958124,
               1.87516174147236,
               1.3580435133394,
               -0.023025382044371,
               0.868949787147092,
               0.818544049664308,
              0.424148875127088,
               0.736624515913625,
               0.582331945383079,
               -0.360646914296501,
               -0.102616395125987,
               0.568374287100884),
  MFTnpl = c(1.12992057802027,
               1.72414763597092,
               1.31992512820668,
               -0.0459400083029988,
               0.877552197432715,
               0.833016259746254,
             0.380956173964173,
               0.612695787806214,
               0.548948423945319,
               -0.415754151769206,
               -0.11377875425023,
               0.5318669978851),
  deltatot = c(1.2949199223707,
                 1.47291843448085,
                 1.80201609548309,
                 0.448439366625241,
                 1.44254893643999,
                 1.24614305780384,
                0.581046925771083,
                 0.578171233537724,
                 0.846725209056708,
                 0.0907660716228413,
                 0.352169086263345,
                 0.756722046864607),
  deltanpl = c(1.14163440022334,
                 1.22744666268519,
                 1.74076846194607,
                 0.38921668722747,
                 1.36582548005673,
                 1.1752183263734,
               0.513444506949558,
                 0.523413611304003,
                 0.847610692032168,
                 0.0306054931267458,
                 0.311101974170304,
                 0.71131177638372),
  nepsraw = c(1275L,1595L,
              1595L,1574L,1591L,
              1592L),
  nrejeps = c(57L,182L,69L,
              35L,0L,0L),
  ngoodtrls = c(845L,1061L,
                  1145L,1144L,1190L,
                  1192L,316L,350L,379L,
                  385L,399L,398L),
  congruency = c("c","i"))

I know this is probably pretty straightforward but for some reason I'm still stuck!

base R:
reshape(df, grep("_", names(df)), direction = 'long', sep="_")
    SID Session nepsraw nrejeps time      MFTtot      MFTnpl   deltatot   deltanpl ngoodtrls id
1.i   1      S1    1275      57    i  1.16096181  1.12992058 1.29491992 1.14163440       845  1
2.i   1      S2    1595     182    i  1.87516174  1.72414764 1.47291843 1.22744666      1061  2
3.i   1      S3    1595      69    i  1.35804351  1.31992513 1.80201610 1.74076846      1145  3
4.i   3      S1    1574      35    i -0.02302538 -0.04594001 0.44843937 0.38921669      1144  4
5.i   3      S2    1591       0    i  0.86894979  0.87755220 1.44254894 1.36582548      1190  5
6.i   3      S3    1592       0    i  0.81854405  0.83301626 1.24614306 1.17521833      1192  6
1.c   1      S1    1275      57    c  0.42414888  0.38095617 0.58104693 0.51344451       316  1
2.c   1      S2    1595     182    c  0.73662452  0.61269579 0.57817123 0.52341361       350  2
3.c   1      S3    1595      69    c  0.58233195  0.54894842 0.84672521 0.84761069       379  3
4.c   3      S1    1574      35    c -0.36064691 -0.41575415 0.09076607 0.03060549       385  4
5.c   3      S2    1591       0    c -0.10261640 -0.11377875 0.35216909 0.31110197       399  5
6.c   3      S3    1592       0    c  0.56837429  0.53186700 0.75672205 0.71131178       398  6

Note that you could get rid of the id column by specifying the idvar argument.
pivot_longer:
pivot_longer(df, contains('_'), names_to = c('.value', 'congruence'), names_sep = '_')

# A tibble: 12 × 10
     SID Session nepsraw nrejeps congruence  MFTtot  MFTnpl deltatot deltanpl ngoodtrls
   <int> <chr>     <int>   <int> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <int>
 1     1 S1         1275      57 i           1.16    1.13     1.29     1.14         316
 2     1 S1         1275      57 c           0.424   0.381    0.581    0.513        845
 3     1 S2         1595     182 i           1.88    1.72     1.47     1.23         350
 4     1 S2         1595     182 c           0.737   0.613    0.578    0.523       1061
 5     1 S3         1595      69 i           1.36    1.32     1.80     1.74         379
 6     1 S3         1595      69 c           0.582   0.549    0.847    0.848       1145
 7     3 S1         1574      35 i          -0.0230 -0.0459   0.448    0.389        385
 8     3 S1         1574      35 c          -0.361  -0.416    0.0908   0.0306      1144
 9     3 S2         1591       0 i           0.869   0.878    1.44     1.37         399
10     3 S2         1591       0 c          -0.103  -0.114    0.352    0.311       1190
11     3 S3         1592       0 i           0.819   0.833    1.25     1.18         398
12     3 S3         1592       0 c           0.568   0.532    0.757    0.711       1192


There might be a smarter solution, but you could use pivot_longer directely followed by pivot_wider like this:
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    matches("_(c|i)$"),
    names_to = c("name", "congruency"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_(c|i)"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
  )

Here your data.frame is named df.
This returns
# A tibble: 12 × 10
     SID Session nepsraw nrejeps congruency  MFTtot  MFTnpl deltatot deltanpl ngoodtrls
   <int> <chr>     <int>   <int> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 S1         1275      57 i           1.16    1.13     1.29     1.14         316
 2     1 S1         1275      57 c           0.424   0.381    0.581    0.513        845
 3     1 S2         1595     182 i           1.88    1.72     1.47     1.23         350
 4     1 S2         1595     182 c           0.737   0.613    0.578    0.523       1061
 5     1 S3         1595      69 i           1.36    1.32     1.80     1.74         379
 6     1 S3         1595      69 c           0.582   0.549    0.847    0.848       1145
 7     3 S1         1574      35 i          -0.0230 -0.0459   0.448    0.389        385
 8     3 S1         1574      35 c          -0.361  -0.416    0.0908   0.0306      1144
 9     3 S2         1591       0 i           0.869   0.878    1.44     1.37         399
10     3 S2         1591       0 c          -0.103  -0.114    0.352    0.311       1190
11     3 S3         1592       0 i           0.819   0.833    1.25     1.18         398
12     3 S3         1592       0 c           0.568   0.532    0.757    0.711       1192

